# Appending new items in a Listview without rendering the whole list - React Native/ React js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In react-native FlatListview I wanted to add a new item in list.

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

the `data` comes from API in addtion of key `a` and b 
ie `data = [{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'},{key: 'c'}]`

whenever the new key comes in it render the whole listview and that creates some performance issue.

so what would be the best way to render only one/two item which is newly added. Its like appending two new items in a listview without rendering the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

This information is directly from the docs...

More complex, multi-select example demonstrating PureComponent usage for perf optimization and avoiding bugs.

By binding the onPressItem handler, the props will remain === and PureComponent will prevent wasteful re-renders unless the actual id, selected, or title props change, even if the components rendered in MyListItem did not have such optimizations.
By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}

  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.